# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 784 into shape (16,16)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, reshape, image-preprocessing

While read `.mat` format data with Python and show as `plt`:

```
import scipy.io as spio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

digits = spio.loadmat('./data/digits.mat', squeeze_me=True)
X = digits['X']
plt.imshow(np.reshape(X[5,:],(16,16)), cmap='Greys')
plt.show()
```

It raises an error: `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 784 into shape (16,16)`.

How could I reshape it correctly? Thanks.

`X`'s shape:

```
print(X.shape)
```

Out:

```
(10000, 784)
```

Data's keys:

```
print(digits.keys())
```

Out:

```
dict_keys(['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'Y', 'X'])
```

Comment: 16*16 = 256. Not sure what your confusion is....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, the solution is easier than you think.

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 784 into shape (16,16).

```
28 x 28 = 784
```

Therefore, you need to reshape into the format `(28,28)` rather than `(16,16)`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems but not with images, it looks similar in a way, so here is how I did mine.
You might need to resize the data first: the data in the code below is your size =784, you do not necessarily need to abandon your shape

```
datas= np.array([data], order='C')
datas.resize((16,16))
datas.shape
```